# Why is the Express (Node.js) request object read-only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using PassportJS but would like to have the user ID (`_id`) available to the front-end client. So I'm trying to splice in `_id` into the `req.user.userInfo` object:

```
/** Create user */
exports.create = function (req, res, next) {
    var newUser = new User(req.body);
    newUser.provider = 'local';

    newUser.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            // Manually provide our own message for 'unique' validation errors, can't do it from schema
            if(err.errors.email.type === 'Value is not unique.') {
                err.errors.email.type = 'The specified email address is already in use.';
            }
            return res.json(400, err);
        }
        // Login after registration
        req.logIn(newUser, function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            // Splice in _id
            req.user.userInfo['_id'] = req.user['_id'];
            console.log('newUser', req.user, req.user.userInfo);

            return res.json(req.user.userInfo);
        });
    });
};
```

However, the `_id` is not present in the returning JSON. Can objects be read-only?

---

**Update:** output of `console.log`:

```
newUser { __v: 0,
  name: 'tom@myemail.com',
  hashedPassword: '$2a$10$r9ZL1JerqDko8zw72q5J5ONYZAWDpHDF1ROt0k35/1fRgfqNedGWG',
  salt: '$2a$10$r9ZL1JerqDko8zw72q5J5O',
  provider: 'local',
  email: 'tom@myemail.com',
  _id: 534552e8ecb0d69648000003,
  role: 'user' } { name: 'tom@myemail.com', role: 'user', provider: 'local' }
```

Comment: Where is `userInfo` coming from? What does `logIn` do?

Comment: Is `req.user` an instance of a mongoose.js Model? If so, can you check the schema for a virtual property defined at `userInfo` and whether `toObject` or `toJSON` transforms are in use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, 2nd theory: While `req` is a normal javascript object, `req.user` is a mongoose.js model instance. Mongoose has a few magical features, namely virtual properties and transforms during `toObject` and `toJSON`. I suspect maybe `req.user.userInfo` is a mongoose virtual, which is why modifications to it get ignored because mongoose regenerates the value every time `req.user.userInfo` is accessed.

If that is true (my evidence is the `__v` property indicating mongoose, you can solve it by doing this:

```
        // Splice in _id
        var userInfo = req.user.userInfo;
        userInfo._id = req.user._id;
        console.log('newUser', req.user, userInfo);

        return res.json(userInfo);
```

And to your larger question, the `req` object is not read-only. There's some simpler bug going on in your code.

Aside: `_id` is a valid identifier so you should just use normal dot syntax, but square bracket syntax is equivalent.

Comment: See update above with log statement - as you can see `_id` is not present in the second object.